# how to remove the file name from Alert fun in intel xdk

Tags: javascript, alert, intel-xdk

when I have run alert function in my real device( iPhone) 
the function works with me , however, the app says "index.html" and the alert below it. How do I remove the "index.html" part?

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function login(oFormElement){
      
     var username1=document.getElementById("user_name").value;
     var pass=document.getElementById("pass_word").value;
     var params="username="+username1+"&password="+pass;
   
        alert(params); 
   }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to customize your alert functions, in a Cordova app (which is what the Intel XDK creates), you need to use the [Cordova "Notification" (aka "dialogs") plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs).

Comment: I used your solution,it was working on emulator ,but didn't work on real device.No dialog displayed. Do u have any idea about that?

Comment: No specific ideas. You do have to call the API provided by the plugin, it does not replace alert(), it provides some alternate functions. Make sure you've waited for the Cordova "deviceready" event before you use any of those APIs, they will not be ready for use until _after_ that event has happened.